# Can't call function in js file

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the noob question, but I searched everywhere and I can't find what's wrong!

I try to call a function from a js file. If I include the same function in the head instead of a js file, it works fine, but not when I try to get it from the file.

Here's the code in the js file:

```
function writetest() {
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

And here's the html code (updated exactly as is in the used document):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="analysscripts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="analysstyle.css">
</head>
<body id="kropp">    
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
writetest();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations and solutions I've found on Stackoverflow and elsewhere online, but I can't get it to work.

Firefox debugger says it's "missing : after property id" (whatever that means). Please help!

Comment: where is **id="demo"** in html?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like you giving an id to the body tag? I'm not sure about that error. However, you function will do nothing, since you have no element with ID = 'demo'

Comment: @forgivenson — "Maybe it doesn't like you giving an id to the body tag?" — no, that's fine.

Comment: The code you've given will not throw the error message you describe. The problem must be elsewhere. Check your [mcve] (I do get a completely different error when I run that code: http://jsbin.com/puduqix/1/edit?html,console )

Comment: @Quentin cool, just a guess. Maybe all the code hasn't been provided to us

Comment: demo id missing in html

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I've included a <p id="demo"></p> beneath the body tag. Still, nothing happens though and the error message remains.

Comment: You need to read @Quentin 's comment above and update your question accordingly

Comment: I've updated the code to exactly as it is in the file. Still get the same error message though and still not working.

Comment: @AndersFlodqvist — As I pointed out earlier — http://jsbin.com/puduqix/1/edit?html,console — that code does not cause that error message. *Something* must be different (even if that something is a browser extension that is spitting out an error message that has nothing to do with your problem).

Comment: Quentin, because of your answer I decided to start over from scratch. Now it's working! I still don't know why, but thanks for bearing with me and letting me know you couldn't find an error. 

Still have a loooot to learn ...

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to add an element with id="demo"

Also, I suggest you execute your "writetest" when the document is loaded and you know for sure your javascript file is loaded and all elements are present.

That's why I wrapped it into an event listener.

```js
function writetest() {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

```html
<body id="kropp">    


   <div id="demo">
   </div>


<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)  {
   writetest();
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do the downvoters care to explain why? the answer is correct. Even if it is on a low quality question for advanced users. But for beginners trying to learn javascript, this is a useful question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Didn't do the trick though, even if it seems like a very logical suggestion.

Comment: Did you include the javascript file? <script src="what_ever_filename_i_gave_my_javascript_file.js"></script> It seems your file isn't loaded.

Answer (score -3):

The ID you're using in your html does not match the ID in your javascript function.
Try this instead:

```
function writetest() {
document.getElementById('kropp').innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the error message that the OP is describing.